# How to pass a variable into the searchResult.Properties[] for the DirectoryServices class

Tags: c#, variables, properties, directoryservices

I am running an active directory search and can get results with the following code (the code is in C# - I am using System.DirectoryServices):

```
foreach (SearchResult searchResult in searchResults)
        {
            foreach (var detailresult1 in searchResult.Properties[ipPhone])
            {
                arrayresult1[i] = detailresult1.ToString();
                i++;
            }
         }
```

Now, I would like to replace ipPhone with a variable that I have set up in an XML file. The purpose for this is that the user can change the variables he/she wants displayed by changing the XML file.

For example, the XML file may be changed from ipPhone to mail, so that the email address is shown.

How do you pass a variable into that statement?

Comment: `ipPhone` already looks like a variable identifier to me. Or, was that meant to be `"ipPhone"`?

Comment: Well... ipPhone is an attribute in active directory. What I wanted to do was to set up an XML file where the user could change ipPhone to another attribute, let say email and then the program will pull up the email attribute instead of ipPhone.   I am still new to C# and visual studio so I was having problems passing that variable over. I think I figured it out by passing the variable to a text box and then obtaining the value from that text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just passed the XLM variable to a textbox and then it worked.